# Git push -nothing to commit, working directory clean

Tags: git

I wanted to create another branch ' *ServerSR* ' but in the end I got *' - nothing to commit, working directory clean'*.
Here are the commands that I did in terminal:

At fist I input **..$ git status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   .babelrc
new file:   _public/css/bootstrap.min.css
...
```

Then I entered **..$ git add -A .** and
**..$ git status**

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   .babelrc
modified:   _public/bundle.js
...
```

then **..$ git checkout -b ServerSR**

```
M   .babelrc
M   _public/bundle.js
...
Switched to a new branch 'ServerSR'
```

after that commited **.. $ git commit -m 'SSR'**

```
[ServerSR 529eefa] SSR
33 files changed, 142 insertions(+), 152 deletions(-)
rewrite _public/bundle.js (85%)
create mode 100644 _public/css/bootstrap.min.css
...
```

And in the end command **.@.$ git push** returns me:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

So it didn't push anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git push -u origin <branch_name>`

In current situation is: `git push -u origin ServerSR`

More general in shell:

```
git push -u origin `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD`
```

Comment: It worked, but  I kind of weird because I saw in video workshop - teacher did: Git push and  in his case it worked fine

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv: `git push` remembers which remote branch it's supposed to push to. This is stored in `.git/config`. By specifying `git push origin ServerSR`, you are telling Git exactly where you want to push to. Adding `-u` makes Git remember your choice for next time.

Comment: I have a bash alias for git push -u origin `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` to push always to proper branch

Answer (score -1):

I am not a pro in git. But this is what I did when I once ran into such response and it worked for me.

Check for the .git file

```
ls -a
```

Remove the .git file

```
rm -rf .git
```

Now initialize git repo.

```
git init
```

and

```
git add .
```

So basically, I removed the existing Git repo and started afresh.